If P is a linear order such that $aPbPcPd$, and $X=\{a,b\}$ and $Y=\{c,d\}$; can I write $XPY$?
I have a very basic doubt regarding the notation of linear orders. Let $\{a,b,c,d\}$ be a set and let $P$ be a linear order on $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $aPbPcPd$. Now, let $X=\{a,b\}$ and $Y=\{c,d\}$.
My question is very simple: is it correct to write $XPY$?
A part of me thinks that writing $XPY$ is not correct because $P$ is not defined on the sets $X$ and $Y$; but another part of me feels that it intuitively makes sense because for all elements $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, we have $xPy$.

If you define $XPY$ to mean $\forall x\in X. \forall y \in Y. xPy$, then it is correct. This kind of abuse of notation is quite common and not shocking.

You don't want to suggest that $P$ is a total order on the collection of pairs (or subsets), but as a partial order I don't see a problem with defining it the way you have.

You can create an ordering on subsets of $P$ in the way you describe, though I'd write it as something like  $P^*$ or $\hat{P}$ to keep the distinction clear.

Without any further definitions, no, it's not correct. But as already mentioned in the comments, you can define $XPY$ for subsets of the set where $P$ is defined in a very natural way, and then you can actually prove that $XPY$ is correct using your newly defined relation. Just be aware that this new relation defined on the subsets won't be a linear order.

The corollary of this answer:  If you want to use the notation $X;P;Y$, then define it first.
